# access variable within a function and put it as the return for another function swift

Tags: ios, function, swift, global-variables, uicollectionview

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView?

    var instanceOfCustomObject: CustomObject = CustomObject()
    var accessToken: NSString!
    var userDefaults: NSUserDefaults!

    var responseDictionary: NSDictionary!
//    var currentResponse: NSArray!


    // the range represents integer values 0, 1, and 2
    // the range now represents integer values 6, 7, and 8

    let colorWheel = ColorWheel()
//    let parse = Parse()

//    var currentResponse: NSArray?
//    struct photoCount {
//    init(responseDictionary: NSDictionary) {
//
//        //        var currentResponse = responseDictionary["data"] as NSDictionary
//
//        var currentResponse = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data") as NSArray
//        var photoCount = currentResponse.count as Int
//        println(photoCount)
//    }
//    }
    var photoCount: Int!

//    private let api = "d4984c8cfa78689bd066d82bec820fd5"



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        self.accessToken = userDefaults!.objectForKey("accessToken") as NSString
        println(self.accessToken)

        //        instanceOfCustomObject.someProperty = "Hello World"
//        var accessToken : NSString? = NSString(instanceOfCustomObject.accessToken)
//        println(accessToken)
//        instanceOfCustomObject.authorize()
//        instanceOfCustomObject.simpleAuth()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
//        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 124, height: 124)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1.0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1.0
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView!)

        getData()

    }

    func getData() -> Void {
        let baseUrl = NSURL(string:"https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=\(self.accessToken)")

        let forcastUrl = NSURL(string: "", relativeToURL: baseUrl)

        //        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: forcastUrl)
        //        println(data)
        let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(baseUrl, completionHandler: { (location: NSURL!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in


            //            var urlContents = NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL(location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
            //            println(urlContents)

            let dataObject = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseUrl)
            //            println(dataObject)
            if (error == nil) {
                let responseDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataObject, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

                var currentResponse = responseDictionary.valueForKeyPath("data") as NSArray

                //                println(currentResponse)
                //                self.currentResponse = currentResponse as NSArray
                self.photoCount = currentResponse.count as Int
                println(self.photoCount)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    //                    self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.temperature)"
                    //                    self.iconView.image = currentWeather.icon!
                    //                    self.currentTimeLabel.text = "At \(currentWeather.currentTime!) it is"
                    //                    self.humidityLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.humidity)"
                    //                    self.percipitationLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.precipProbability)"
                    //                    self.summeryLabel.text = "\(currentWeather.summary)"
                    //
                    //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                    //
                    //                    self.refreshButton.hidden = false
                })

            } else {

                let networkIssueController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "I got 99 problems but a bitch ain't one", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                networkIssueController.addAction(okButton)
                let cancelButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
                networkIssueController.addAction(cancelButton)

                self.presentViewController(networkIssueController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    //Stop refresh animation
                    //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    //                    self.refreshActivityIndicator.hidden = true
                    //                    self.refreshButton.hidden = false

                })

            }

        })

        downloadTask.resume()

    }
```

In the getData() function a variable nameed "currentResponse" retrieves an array of urls. I then count the array and assign the number to a variable named "photoCount"

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


//        var photoCount = parse.photoCount(currentResponse)
        return photoCount
    }
```

I want to use the "photoCount" variable to tell my collection view function how many sections it should have! there are 20 urls so it should output 20 squares but currently photoCount is nil! Do I need to make "photoCount" a global variable? Been stuck on this for ages please help!

Answer (score 0):

Size of your collection view is assigned **nil** when your view controller is loaded and is not updated any time, any where. You have to reload your collection view asynchronously.

In your **getData** function, put this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.photoCount = currentResponse.count as Int
    self.collectionView.reloadData()        
})
```